# Why `socket.disconnect()` isn't working when `useEffect` hook is invoked for the first time?

Tags: react-hooks, socket.io

I'm trying to add a user to `users` array inside my server when the user joins a socket.io room. When a user joins a room, the user is saved twice inside the `users` array since `useEffect` hook is called twice when the component is rendered for the first time. That's why I added `socket.disconnect()` inside the `useEffect` cleanup function which removes the user from the `users` array. However, `socket.disconnect()` isn't working when useEffect is called for the first time ever. But it's working as expected when the component is unmounted.

**Client**

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    socket.connect();
    socket.on("connect", logSocketStatus);

    if (user) {
      socket.emit("join", { userId, roomId });
    }

    return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
      socket.off("connect", logSocketStatus);
    };
  }, [user, itemId]);
```

**Server**

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("join", ({ userId, roomId }) => {
    addUser({ id: socket.id, userId, roomId });
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    const user = removeUser(socket.id);
    if (user) {
      io.to(user.roomId).emit(
        "comment",
        `User with id: ${user.userId} has left.`
      );
    }
  });
});
```

**users.js in Server**

```
const users = [];

function getUser(id) {
  return users.find((user) => user.id === id);
}

function addUser({ id, userId, roomId }) {
  const user = { id, userId, roomId };
  users.push(user);
  return user;
}

function removeUser(id) {
  const userIndex = users.findIndex((user) => user.id === id);
  if (userIndex > -1) {
    return users.splice(userIndex, 1)[0];
  }
}

module.exports = {
  users,
  getUser,
  addUser,
  removeUser,
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "socket.disconnect() isn't working"? Please provide the debugging details